# Grafana with Elastic - Show requests count toguether with average response time

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm new at Grafana and I'm trying to create a graph that shows the requests count together with the average response time for the requests, I was able to create my requests count but now I'm struggling to add the information with the requests time, there is an option to show both information inside a panel? Or do I need to create two panels, one with the request count and another with the average time?

And another question, there is an option to show the average time in milliseconds?